# How do I wrap a callback with async await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

My function returns a promise that resolves as soon as the HTTP server starts. This is my code:

```
function start() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) {
        this.server = Http.createServer(app);
        this.server.listen(port, () => {
            resolve();
        });
    })
}
```

How do I convert the start function to async/await?

Comment: Why do you want to convert the code to `async/await` pattern? Given the code at Question the result would effectively be adding more code to the pattern.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Include `async` before the function declaration and `await` the `Promise` constructor. Though note, you would essentially be adding code to the existing pattern. `await` converts a value to a `Promise`, though the code in the question already uses the `Promise` constructor.

```
async function start() {
    let promise = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.server = Http.createServer(app);
        this.server.listen(port, () => {
            resolve();
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {throw err});

    return promise
}

start()
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: You merely wrapped the promise. I want to get rid of the callback.

Comment: You cannot "get rid of the callback" simply by using `Promise` or `async/await`

Comment: You would need to re-write the code base of `Http.createServer()` to remove the callback pattern from the code

Comment: Well i think you answered my question... In fact i didn't really had a question... I think i am just having problems accepting that this async await feature is completely useless, shallow and is just a bit of syntax sugar. Why would they add this to the language if it doesn't replace the previous asynchronous mechanisms?

Comment: @TiagoBértolo async was mean to make promise chains behave more like synchronous code. It's sugar, but very useful sugar (for loops, while loops, if statements, and try/catch work with promises now)

Comment: Well my while loops will have async instead of thens? So what? It is just sugar. It is going to annoy and confuse new programmers and it does not solve my real problems or add new features like RXJS does.

Comment: @TiagoBértolo: other languages have async/await as well, so it’s not something uncommon. It can make code a lot more readable. Alone marking a function as async tells the reader that this function returns a promise, without even having to look at the `return` statement. But being able to use try...catch and throw is probably an even bigger advantage. But as always, if you don’t like it you don’t have to use it :)

Comment: The `.catch(...)` will never fire if you don't call `reject()` from within the Promise, for god's sake at least reject on `this.server.on("error", ...)`.

Answer (score 11):

Creating a `new Promise` like the other answers suggest works fine in this case, but as a general rule, [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) can stop you from writing the same thing many times.

So you can do something like this instead: (node.js v8.0.0+)

```
const util = require('util');
async function start() {
    let server = Http.createServer(app);
    await util.promisify(server.listen.bind(server))(port);
}
```

`util.promisify(some_function)` takes a function which normally accepts a callback, and returns a new, wrapped version of this function that instead returns a promise.

With more explained steps:

```
let server = Http.createServer(app);
// .bind() is needed so that .listen() keeps the correct `this` context when it is called.
// If your function does not require any specific context, leave off .bind()
let listen_promise = util.promisify(server.listen.bind(server));
await listen_promise(port);
```

More advanced promisification can be done with [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html).

Comment: Nice, clean, and simple.  util.promisify().

Comment: Great solution always simple

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
const doRequest = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) {
    this.server = Http.createServer(app);
    this.server.listen(port, () => {
        resolve();
    });
})

async function start() {
    await doRequest()
}
```

Something like this, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

This is something I've stumbled upon when while trying to make the HTTP server `listen` function truly promisified. The biggest problem is not to resolve on `listening` callback, but to handle the errors on startup.

Wrapping in Promise and attempt to `catch` (as other answers suggest) or try-catch block won't have any effect, because any Node.js server, `net` or derived `http`/`https`, are `EventEmitter` instances, which means no errors are thrown. Instead, they are emitted as the `error` event.

So, considering all of the above, correct implementation of promisified server `listen` function is as follows:

```
const { createServer } = require('http');

const server = createServer();

const listen = async (port, host) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const listeners = {};

    listeners.onceError = (error) => {
      server.removeListener('listening', listeners.onceListening);
      reject(error);
    };

    listeners.onceListening = () => {
      server.removeListener('error', listeners.onceError);
      resolve();
    };

    server
      .prependOnceListener('error', listeners.onceError)
      .prependOnceListener('listening', listeners.onceListening);

    server.listen(port, host);
  });
}
```

Reject and resolve calls inside handlers are prepended to the top of the listeners stack, and they mutually cancel each other - whoever fires first.

That way it's guaranteed that the `listen` method will either start the server or throw a catchable error.

Answer (score -1):

I created a basic utility that **may not be the most proper way to do**, but it is way **more readable**, in my opinion:

```js
// Async time-out utility
const timeout = async ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function start() {
    let output;

    this.server = Http.createServer(app);
    this.server.listen(port, () => {
        output = true; // Or can be any data that you want to return
    });
    while (output === undefined) await timeout(10);
    return output;
}
```

This is the basic concept. However be **careful** if your promise may return undefined values has the function will run forever (but this will not crash).